# MongoDB: why is the MMAP storage engine still the default storage engine

Tags: mongodb

MongoDB: why is the MMAP storage engine still the default storage engine when wire-tiger is now available?

please explain the differences between them. thank you.

Comment: Why not? For one most peoples storage is already using "MMAP" and it's the simplest default option. Also while Wired Tiger does some pretty cool things for "some people" it doesn't necessarily do it for "all people". So you generally don't go and make "breaking changes" to peoples data storage unless you really need to. Not my downvote BTW. But I'd expect more for the style of question asked here.

Answer (score 0):

Because MMAP is a legacy engine.

Please watch these short videos, they talk about main properties, differences between the engines:

WiredTiger:
https://youtu.be/O9TGqK3FBX8

MMAP:
https://youtu.be/PZCdLVB4lw4

https://youtu.be/9nYFnlM4vYw